# How to split R column into separate columns selectively

Tags: r, split

**Problem**

I want to **selectively** split some strings in a column. My limited ability with regular expressions is a problem, but your thoughts would be welcome.

**Reprex**

My starting dataset:

```
media <- c("TV, Radio and Games", "Theatre, Festival", "Festival and Arts", "TV", "Theatre", "Radio")
type <- c("Indoors", "Outdoors", "Outdoors", "Indoors", "Outdoors", "Indoors")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(media, type))
df

#   media                type
# 1 TV, Radio and Games    Indoors
# 2   Theatre, Festival    Outdoors
# 3   Festival and Arts    Outdoors
# 4                  TV    Indoors
# 5             Theatre    Outdoors
# 6               Radio    Indoors
```

**Output Wanted**

```
media2 <- c("TV", "Radio", "Games", "Theatre", "Festival", "Festival and Arts", "TV", "Theatre", "Radio")
type2 <- c("Indoors", "Indoors", "Indoors", "Outdoors", "Outdoors", "Outdoors", "Indoors", "Outdoors", "Indoors")

df2 <- cbind(media2, type2)
df2

#      media2              type2     
# [1,] "TV"                "Indoors" 
# [2,] "Radio"             "Indoors" 
# [3,] "Games"             "Indoors" 
# [4,] "Theatre"           "Outdoors"
# [5,] "Festival"          "Outdoors"
# [6,] "Festival and Arts" "Outdoors"
# [7,] "TV"                "Indoors" 
# [8,] "Theatre"           "Outdoors"
# [9,] "Radio"             "Indoors"
```

**Attempted Solution**

```
df3 <- df %>% 
  tidyr::separate(media, c("media1", "media2"), ", ") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(1:2, names_to = "media_type", values_to = "media") %>% 
  select(media, type) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(media))

#   media             type    
# 1 TV                Indoors 
# 2 Radio and Games   Indoors 
# 3 Theatre           Outdoors
# 4 Festival          Outdoors
# 5 Festival and Arts Outdoors
# 6 TV                Indoors 
# 7 Theatre           Outdoors
# 8 Radio             Indoors
```

This gets me some of the way there, but I also want "Radio and Games" split up, but not "Festival and Arts". I cannot split it using " and ", as that would split them both.

Comment: Could you describe your conditions why "Radio and Games" should be split up, but "Festival and Arts" shouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(media = ifelse(str_detect(media, ","),
                        str_split(media, pattern = "\\s*(,|and)\\s*"),
                        media)) %>% 
  unnest(media)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  media             type    
  <chr>             <chr>   
1 TV                Indoors 
2 Radio             Indoors 
3 Games             Indoors 
4 Theatre           Outdoors
5 Festival          Outdoors
6 Festival and Arts Outdoors
7 TV                Indoors 
8 Theatre           Outdoors
9 Radio             Indoors
```

Comment: I fixed an error. Missed the `Festival and Arts` part of OPs question.

Comment: Fine regex Martin Gal! +1.

Comment: This worked beautifully. So am I right in assuming that this method excluded "Festival and Arts" by only splitting those cells with a comma in them?

Comment: Yes. I search for strings containing "," and only split those but then using ","  and "and".

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse workaround:

The problem is with `Festival and Arts` because it contents and, otherwise it would be a simple `seperate_rows`

So:

1. save `Festival and Arts` in `preserve <- df[3,]`
2. `filter` out rows with `Festival and Arts`
3. add an `id` to perform `separate_rows`
4. after that filter out rows with `and`
5. and bind to `preserve`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

preserve <- df[3,]

df %>% 
    filter(!grepl('Festival and Arts', media)) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(media, id, sep = "[^[:alnum:].]+", convert = TRUE) %>% 
    filter(!grepl('and', media)) %>% 
    bind_rows(preserve) %>% 
    select(-id)
```

output:

```
media             type    
  <chr>             <chr>   
1 TV                Indoors 
2 Radio             Indoors 
3 Games             Indoors 
4 Theatre           Outdoors
5 Festival          Outdoors
6 TV                Indoors 
7 Theatre           Outdoors
8 Radio             Indoors 
9 Festival and Arts Outdoors
>
```

Answer (score 1):

An option will be to look behind if *Arts* follows *and* using `(?! Arts)`.

```
x <- strsplit(df$media, "\\s*(,|and(?! Arts))\\s*", perl=TRUE)
data.frame(media=unlist(x), type=rep(df$type, lengths(x)))
#              media     type
#1                TV  Indoors
#2             Radio  Indoors
#3             Games  Indoors
#4           Theatre Outdoors
#5          Festival Outdoors
#6 Festival and Arts Outdoors
#7                TV  Indoors
#8           Theatre Outdoors
#9             Radio  Indoors
```

Or splitting only those which have at least one `,`.

```
i <- grepl(",", df$media)
x <- ifelse(i, str_split(df$media, pattern = "\\s*(,|and)\\s*"), df$media)
data.frame(media=unlist(x), type=rep(df$type, lengths(x)))
```